# Java 11 and javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, payara

I'm using Payara 5.29.0 enterprise server which support Jakarta EE 8.

I'm trying to port the code for Java 11.

When I compile there comes error:

```
    cannot find symbol
    [ERROR]   symbol:   variable PortableRemoteObject
```

The code contains `javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow`  which was used before EJB3.

Is javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject in some library so I could add it to the maven pom.xml?

I tried dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

but I got still same error.

I could port the code to the EJB3, but I wonder is it possible to handle this only adding the maven dependency?

Answer (score 2):

javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject was part of the JDK itself up until JDK10. It was removed in JDK11. Everything rmi was removed in 11 if I understand https://openjdk.org/jeps/320 correctly.

Comment: No, rmi is still there in 21.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.rmi/module-summary.html